# Subnormal number and gradual underflow

Tags: floating-point

I have read why use gradual underflow.

Gradual underflow satisfies the following formula.

a != b then a-b != 0

I see why.
But what else do we need to be satisfied with?
And how to prove it?

The following does not seem to hold.

ab = 0 then a=0 or b=0, a/b = 0 then a=0

Is this okay?

Comment: Another interesting property of gradual underflow is that the difference between adjacent numbers is a monotonic function of their absolute magnitude. With abrupt underflow, there is a bigger gap between 0 and the smallest strictly positive number than between it and its immediate successor.

Answer (score 0):

> But what else do we need to be satisfied with?

Avoids abrupt subtraction differences with small values. [@Patricia Shanahan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658351/subnormal-number-and-gradual-underflow/57661417#comment101766924_57658351)

Subtracting various nearby values several powers-of-2 just above `DBL_MIN` would otherwise result in 0.  With sub-normals, the difference is gradual and non-zero.

> The following does not seem to hold.
>
> ab = 0 then a=0 or b=0, a/b = 0 then a=0
>
> Is this okay?

Yes.  When  `a,b` are both non-zero and much less than `sqrt(DBL_MIN)`, the product *rounds* to zero.

Similar situation can occur with `a/b`: `a = sqrt(DBL_MIN)` and `b much greater than sqrt(DBL_MAX)`.

In these cases, the gradual precision loss of sub-normal is not the key issue.  Finite range of the exponents causes a rounding to 0.

---

Sub-normals also allow a non-zero answer to a [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) function for all finite `double`.